# How to delete a symbolic link file in the samba server

Tags: 20.04, samba

When I try to delete (or rename) a symbolic link file in the shared folder from Windows, it tell me that I don't have enough permission, whatever the target is (even it doesn't exist). The file is simply created with `ln -s target test` command. The attribute of the file is `lrwxrwxrwx`. I could create/edit/delete regular files in this folder. I have tried `follow symlinks = no`, it's not help.

Answer (score 0):

The owner and the group of the symbolic link file might be wrong.

If you are not the owner of the samba share, send this answer to the owner of the samba share

If you can ssh into that server or connect directly, check the owner and permissions of the symbolic file via

`ls -l symbolic_link_file`

if the username does not match with the samba user, you are not allowed to change that file.

if you need to change the file name
`sudo mv symbolic_link_file new_name`

if you need to remove the file
`sudo rm symbolic_link_file`

if you need to make the symbolic link file accessible by samba, change the owner of the file
`sudo chown samba_user:samba_user symbolic_link_file`

Comment: The mode is `lrwxrwxrwx`

Comment: The mode on symlinks is ALWAYS lrwxrwxrwx, the effective mode is the mode of the target. Otherwise i could get access to YOUR files by linking to them ;)